# How to search for a letter in a user generated word

Tags: python-3.x

Would like the code in choice 2 to search for a letter in the word created from choice 1. I can not seem to find a solution to this.

```
if choice==1:
    print ("Enter a Word")
    minput= input()

    wordList= list (minput)
    print (wordList)

    mainMenu()

if choice==2:
    letter=['a,b,c,d, e, f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z']
    counter=0
    searchletter=input('Enter letter to search\t')

    while counter<len(letter) and searchletter!=letter[counter]:
        counter+=1
    if counter <len(letter):
        print(searchletter,'found')
    else:
        print(searchletter, ' Not found')
        mainMenu()
```

Comment: You need to fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the `while` loop. Currently, when searching, your loop exits at the first character that isn't your search letter. Instead, you could simply use

```
print("found" if searchletter in word else "not found")
```

and put the variable name for your word in `word`.

```
>>> word = "testme"
>>> searchletter = "t"
>>> print("found" if searchletter in word else "not found")
found
>>> searchletter = "f"
>>> print("found" if searchletter in word else "not found")
not found
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I seemed to have over complicated it. Thanks!

Comment: As an added feature is there any possibility for python to count and display the characters in the word?